# Regular expression to match characters at beginning of line only

Tags: regex

I am trying to work on regular expressions. I have a mainframe file which has several fields. I have a flat file parser which distinguishes several types of records based on the first three letters of every line. How do I write a regular expression where the first three letters are 'CTR'.

Answer (score 142):

Beginning of line or beginning of string?

### Start and end of string

```
/^CTR.*$/
```

`/` = delimiter
`^` = start of string
`CTR` = literal CTR
`$` = end of string
`.*` = zero or more of any character except newline

### Start and end of line

```
/^CTR.*$/m
```

`/` = delimiter
`^` = start of line
`CTR` = literal CTR
`$` = end of line
`.*` = zero or more of any character except newline
`m` = enables multi-line mode, this sets regex to treat every line as a string, so `^` and `$` will match start and end of line

While in multi-line mode you can still match the start and end of the string with `\A\Z` permanent anchors

```
/\ACTR.*\Z/m
```

`\A` = means start of string
`CTR` = literal CTR
`.*` = zero or more of any character except newline
`\Z` = end of string
`m` = enables multi-line mode

As such, another way to match the start of the line would be like this:

```
/(\A|\r|\n|\r\n)CTR.*/
```

or

```
/(^|\r|\n|\r\n)CTR.*/
```

`\r` = carriage return / old Mac OS newline
`\n` = line-feed / Unix/Mac OS X newline
`\r\n` = windows newline

Note, if you are going to use the backslash `\` in some program string that supports escaping, like the php double quotation marks `""` then you need to escape them first

so to run `\r\nCTR.*` you would use it as `"\\r\\nCTR.*"`

Comment: The moneyball for me was, "**_`m` = enables multi-line mode, this sets regex to treat every line as a string, so `^` and `$` will match start and end of line_**" -- worth highlighting, I think. I assumed that would be the case as soon as I put in `^` & `$`. Not so! And happy 100.

Answer (score 25):

```
^CTR
```

or

```
^CTR.*
```

edit:

To be more clear: `^CTR` will match start of line and those chars. If all you want to do is match for a line itself (and already have the line to use), then that is all you really need. But if this is the case, you may be better off using a prefab `substr()` type function. I don't know, what language are you are using. But if you are trying to match and grab the line, you will need something like `.*` or `.*$` or whatever, depending on what language/regex function you are using.

Comment: the .* matches for everything after the CTR, up to end of line or end of string, depending on what language you are using

Answer (score 23):

### Regex symbol to match at beginning of a line:

```
^
```

Add the string you're searching for (`CTR`) to the regex like this:

```
^CTR
```

Example: [regex](https://regex101.com/r/uTa1PF/2)

**That should be enough!**

However, if you need to get the text from the whole line in your language of choice, add a "match anything" pattern `.*`:

```
^CTR.*
```

Example: [more regex](https://regex101.com/r/X6FgyM/2)

If you want to get crazy, use the **end of line** matcher

```
$
```

Add that to the growing regex pattern:

```
^CTR.*$
```

Example: [lets get crazy](https://regex101.com/r/EZSp5e/2)

**Note:** Depending on how and where you're using regex, you might have to use a multi-line modifier to get it to match multiple lines. There could be a whole discussion on the best strategy for picking lines out of a file to process them, and some of the strategies would require this:

**Multi-line flag** `m` (this is specified in various ways in various languages/contexts)

```
/^CTR.*/gm
```

Example: [we had to use m on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/EZSp5e/2)

Answer (score 8):

Try `^CTR.\*`, which literally **means start of line, CTR, anything**.

This will be **case-sensitive**, and setting non-case-sensitivity will depend on your programming language, or use `^[Cc][Tt][Rr].\*` if cross-environment case-insensitivity matters.

Answer (score 5):

```
^CTR.*$
```

matches a line starting with `CTR`.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how to apply that to your file on your server, but typically, the regex to match the beginning of a string would be :

```
^CTR
```

*The `^` means beginning of string / line*

Answer (score 2):

There's are ambiguities in the question.

What is your input string? Is it the entire file? Or is it 1 line at a time? Some of the answers are assuming the latter. I want to answer the former.

What would you like to return from your regular expression? The fact that you want a true / false on whether a match was made? Or do you want to extract the entire line whose start begins with CTR? I'll answer you only want a true / false match.

To do this, we just need to determine if the CTR occurs at either the start of a file, or immediately following a new line.

```
/(?:^|\n)CTR/
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(?i)^[ \r\n]*CTR

(?i) -- case insensitive -- Remove if case sensitive.
[ \r\n]  -- ignore space and new lines
* -- 0 or more times the same
CTR - your starts with string.
```