# PowerShell script to get logged in user

Tags: powershell

I am looking to run a script on a remote machine using an automation tool that runs the scripts in the system context.

What I have so far:

```
$userId = Get-Process -IncludeUserName explorer | % username | sort Username -Unique
Write-Host $userid.ToLower()
```

Results:

```
Get-Process : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name
'IncludeUserName'.
At line:1 char:39
+ $userId = Get-Process -IncludeUserName <<<<  explorer | % username | sort Username -Unique
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-Process], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetProcessCommand

ToLower : You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:2 char:27
+ Write-Host $userid.ToLower <<<< ()
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (ToLower:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

Any ideas how to help this script? Or the cause of the errors?

Comment: I'd suspect you're using PowerShell v3 or older. Apparently the parameter `-IncludeUserName` was [introduced with PowerShell v4](http://mikefrobbins.com/2013/06/27/powershell-version-4-new-feature-a-username-property-has-been-added-to-get-process-output-objects/).

Comment: If you can't upgrade to PowerShell v4 or newer use [WMI](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32018396/1630171) to work around the issue.

Answer (score 2):

The error says it all; the switch `-IncludeUserName` is not available on your computer. That's because it requires PowerShell 4.0 or above like Ansgar mentioned.

One solution is to install the latest Windows Mangement Framework (WMF) which includes the latest version of PowerShell.

You can also use the WMI-class `Win32_Process` to get the user and/or domain by calling the object's `GetOwner()`-method. Ex:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Process -Filter "Name = 'explorer.exe'" |
ForEach-Object { $_.GetOwner() | % { "$($_.Domain)\$($_.User)" } } |
Sort-Object -Unique
```

Comment: Ok, I ran that and I got a username. I've discovered that the requirements are that we get a result of 'domain\username'. Not sure if that is possible.

Comment: Worked like a champ, Frode!! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

the following script might help you. I'm not completely certain if the invoked command will get the remote logged in user, because I'm not on a work computer right now but it came from the internet so it must be true.

```
$Computers = (Get-Content "\\<sharedrive\<directory>\Computers.txt)

Foreach ($Computer in $Computers){ `
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer -ScriptBlock `
{Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem).Username} `
}
```