# Showing currently logged in user in a PowerShell running from a RMM Software as SYSTEM

Tags: powershell, system

i searched hours of my time and saw many ideas for this scenario but nothing worked for my like it should (i tested every code i saw on my own machine but nothing got me to the result i wanted.)

background: we are using a script in our RMM Software to Rename the Agents

> $benutzer = [Environment]::UserName
> Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\Software\MMSOFT Design\PC Monitor" -Name ComputerName -Value "$env:USERDOMAIN - $env:Computername - $benutzer"

This script gives us for the $env:USERNAME the user SYSTEM but we actually want the real USERNAME which is logged into this system.

Please help me out :)

Answer (score 0):

The environment variable `[System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('username')` will give you the username for the executor of the script, in your case that is `System` because this is user who ran the code.

If you want to user the environment variable for the user, you must make it so the script been ran from or on behalf of the user, this also means that user must have "permissions" to modify the registry.

If I understand right, you need to know who is the "Logged in user" for the machine where that script runs, unfortunately there is nothing available from PowerShell that do that to my knowledge, instead you could use the build-in tool [query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/query) for Windows machines, which will provide you with a list with all logged in users to that machine, you would need to further test it to get what you want from it, the output looks like this :

```
PS C:\Users\t-user> query user
 USERNAME              SESSIONNAME        ID  STATE   IDLE TIME  LOGON TIME
>t-user                console             1  Active      none   8/29/2022 11:58 AM
```

The trick with `query user` is that it will provide you with the list of users in case more than one have logged in.

I see what you are trying to do, and here is a "[dirty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39212183/easier-way-to-parse-query-user-in-powershell-or-quser)" example of doing it :

```
$loggedUserList= query user

if($loggedUserList.count -eq 2){
    $user = $loggedUserList -split ">" -replace '\s\s+', ';' | convertfrom-csv -Delimiter ';' | select -ExpandProperty username
    Write-Host "Logged in user is - $user"
}else{
    Write-Host "More than one user have signed"
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but i need to get only the output "t-user" to get this working to rename the machine with the above posted script. is this possible?

Comment: It is possible, but it is not elegant solution, check the updated answer.

Comment: i posted a new thread with an answer, please check down below

Comment: @SaschaHofmann stackoverflow does not work like that, if my answer have helped you resolve your problem, you can mark it as "Answer" so it can help others.

Comment: it did not help me get the USERNAME in my script. please see down there

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is a year old but this was answered here:
[Finding current logged on user(s) while running as SYSTEM (no environment variables)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32017531/finding-current-logged-on-users-while-running-as-system-no-environment-variab)

That page provides two methods of obtaining the current logged on user from a powershell script running as the system user.

Displays User instead of Computer/User or Domain/User.

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -Filter "Name='explorer.exe'" |
ForEach-Object { $_.GetOwner() } |
Select-Object -Unique -Expand User
```

Displays Computer/User or Domain/User 2 times

```
$User = tasklist /v /FI "IMAGENAME eq explorer.exe" /FO list | find "User Name:"
$User = $User.Substring(14)
```