# cmd command to display connected user and client names

Tags: cmd, client, windows-server

I am looking for cmd command to list all user and client names connected to Windows server. This info can be seen at user tab of task manager but I need with cmd command. I can get user name but none of them display client name.

- query user
- query session
- query termserver
- query session
- netstat
- ipconfig/all

Is there any cmd command to display client name?

Thanks,

Comment: `reg query "HKCU\Volatile Environment" -v ClientName -s`?

Comment: @jJosefZ I connected to server, executed from cmd of server, it displayed only my computer's name (current user) . I need all computers' name connected to server. Also I need this info together with username. Is not there any command displaying all users/client name couple?

Comment: what exactly do you mean with "connected"? RDP-Connections, Shared Drives or just "on the same network"?

Comment: @Stephan, connected via Remote Desktop. I need to get which users are connected from which client (computername)

Comment: @Stephan "query user" command display username, not client (ip address or computer name). On the other hand, "rwinsta" command displays ip address, not user. Is not there any command display both of them?