# View ALL users logged on to Windows 10 computer

Tags: windows, powershell

I am trying to view all users currently accessing my computer on Windows 10.
Using the following Powershell command shows me all users:

`(Get-CimInstance Win32_LoggedOnUser).antecedent.name | Select-Object -Unique`

This is great, as it also shows users logged in via PSRemote sessions. So let's say user `A` logs into my PC (`PC-B`) via an interactive PSRemote session:

`Enter-PSSession -ComputerName PC-B`

It will show me that the user is logged on. Yet once user `A` closes the PSRemote session, the username is still being listed. Also the `Get-CimInstance` command also doesn't show users that might be accessing a specific network share on `PC-B`.

Is there a way to view ALL users logged in, whether it is via Network Share, Remote, RDP or locally? Seeing users accessing a Network Share is not so important, but all other kinds are. Since the users in question are all domain users, do I have to query the DC?

Comment: Maybe this helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23219718/powershell-script-to-see-currently-logged-in-users-domain-and-machine-status

Comment: @TobyU I have checked that question, but none of the provided answers satisfy the requirements

Answer (score 4):

The below one line will return a list of logged on users.

```
query user /server:PcHostname
```