# Can you run quser with a PSCredential object?

Tags: powershell, cmd, solarwinds-orion

## Question

I'm writing SolarWinds SAM script that can monitor logged in users on a remote machine.  I wanted to use `quser`  rather than a [WMI/CIM based solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23220056/6466149) because `quser` provides exactly the data that i'm looking for.

The kicker is that the monitoring application provides a `PSCredential` object to use in order to authenticate with remote machines, something that `quser` can't use.

## Code

When running with no credential object I get the following.

```
quser /server:'testserver1'
```

## Output

```
No User exists for *
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Answer

The answer to this dilemma was painfully obvious once I realized it.  You can simply use the `Invoke-Command` cmdlet with the `-Credential` and `-ScriptBlock` parameter to run the `quser` command on the remote server with the appropriate user context.

One final note - if you need help parsing the output of `quser` into a more PowerShell friendly object, see [Get-LoggedOnUser](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-LoggedOnUser-Gathers-7cbe93ea).  It's a fantastic script that handles all of the string parsing necessary to get the properties from the `quser` output.

## Code

```
$Server = 'testserver1'
$Credential = Get-Credential
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Server -ScriptBlock { quser } -Credential $Credential
```

## Output

```
 USERNAME              SESSIONNAME        ID  STATE   IDLE TIME  LOGON TIME
 a-srz                 rdp-tcp#0           2  Active         19  6/2/2020 10:19 AM
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the below command:

```
quser -server $server
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).