# quser language independent parsing in powershell

Tags: powershell

I would like to query all users currently logged in to my computer with powershell. My current solution looks like this:

```
$userObject = quser /server:localhost 2>&1 | ForEach-Object -Process { ($_ -replace '\s{2,}', ';').Trim() } | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ';'
```

This gives me the currently logged in users, but the language for the header column depends on the system language. So if I run the script on a system with english as system language I get the following result

```
USERNAME SESSIONNAME ID STATE  IDLE  TIME     LOGON TIME
random   console     1  Active none  4/7/2021 6:52 AM
```

If I run the exactly same command on a german system I get the following:

```
 BENUTZERNAME   SITZUNGSNAME  ID  STATUS  LEERLAUF   ANMELDEZEIT
 random         console       1   Aktiv   1+02:29    07.04.2021 19:10
```

The same on a french system, you get it...

I also tried to replace the default headers with my custom ones by using this code

```
$header = 'UserName', 'SessionName', 'ID', 'State', 'IdleTime', 'LogonTime'
$userObject = quser /server:localhost 2>&1 | Select-Object -Skip 1    | ForEach-Object -Process { ($_ -replace '\s{2,}', ';').Trim() } | ConvertFrom-Csv -Header $header -Delimiter ';'
```

but this only changes the headers but not the language dependent "state" property, so if I would like to filter the users by the state I would still have to convert the property to the correct language.

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Not necessarily, you can filter using operators such as `-like "A*"`.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: @steloe no, not really.. i just lived with the fact that depending on the system language the output could be wrong

Comment: Maybe my answer here might be the solution? https://stackoverflow.com/a/67802006/843345

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
chcp 65001
```

Before your command. The output is always in English in my case.