# Want to logoff specific user of remote machines not having AD domain environment

Tags: powershell

I am seeking for the help to log off specific user from PC via PowerShell script. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Is this an AD Domain environment?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18192746/powershell-log-off-remote-session ?

Comment: Nope, I haven't AD domain environment. I am remotely manage all this.