# Regular Expression for Postal Code starting with H character

Tags: php, regex

I have Regualar expression for Postal Codes

```
 [ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXYabceghjklmnprstvxy]{1}\d{1}[A-Za-z]-{1} *\d{1}[A-Za-z]{1}\d{1}|[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXYabceghjklmnprstvxy]{1}\d{1}[A-Za-z]{1} *\d{1}[A-Za-z]{1}\d{1}
```

This works fine.

But I want only Postal codes that starts from "H" character.

For example: `H2X 1X8`

But the issue is that this regular expression for those postal codes as well which does not start with "H"

e.g `j4k1a4`

Suggest me, how to modify this regular expression so that It can work for only postal codes starting with "H" character.

I apreciate any response.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
^[Hh]{1}\d{1}[A-Za-z]-{1} *\d{1}[A-Za-z]{1}\d{1}|^[Hh]{1}\d{1}[A-Za-z]{1} *\d{1}[A-Za-z]{1}\d{1}
```

Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5516119/regular-expression-to-match-characters-at-beginning-of-line-only)

If the string you are trying to match is not in the starting of the line you can use below `regex`

```
[Hh]{1}\d{1}[A-Za-z]-{1} *\d{1}[A-Za-z]{1}\d{1}|[Hh]{1}\d{1}[A-Za-z]{1} *\d{1}[A-Za-z]{1}\d{1}
```

you can test with different inputs [here](https://pythex.org/?regex=[Hh]%7B1%7D%5Cd%7B1%7D[A-Za-z]-%7B1%7D%20*%5Cd%7B1%7D[A-Za-z]%7B1%7D%5Cd%7B1%7D%7C[Hh]%7B1%7D%5Cd%7B1%7D[A-Za-z]%7B1%7D%20*%5Cd%7B1%7D[A-Za-z]%7B1%7D%5Cd%7B1%7D&test_string=130%20de%20la%20barre%20apt%20%231103%20130de%20labarre%2C%20j4k1a4%2C%20H2X%201X8&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0)

Comment: Thank you so much for your response.
It seems good. But It is not working in php for my string:
<?php
$regExp = '/^[Hh]{1}\d{1}[A-Za-z]-{1} *\d{1}[A-Za-z]{1}\d{1}|^[Hh]{1}\d{1}[A-Za-z]{1} *\d{1}[A-Za-z]{1}\d{1}/';
preg_match($regExp, "130 de la barre apt #1103 130de labarre, j4k1a4, H2X 1X8", $matches);
print_r($matches);
?>

Comment: I added PHP code which I used with yoru regular expression. It did not extract postal code from it.
Please review it and suggest me that how it can be fixed.

Comment: this works `<?php $regExp = '/[Hh]{1}\d{1}[A-Za-z]-{1} *\d{1}[A-Za-z]{1}\d{1}|[Hh]{1}\d{1}[A-Za-z]{1} *\d{1}[A-Za-z]{1}\d{1}/'; preg_match($regExp, "130 de la barre apt #1103 130de labarre, j4k1a4, H2X 1X8", $matches); print_r($matches); ?>`

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your regex to:

```
\b(?i)h\d[a-z]-? *\d[a-z]\d\b
```

where `(?i)` means case insensitive.

Comment: @Maria: How did you test it?  This regex is virtually identical to the one I came up with, and it seems to work: [`'/\bH\d[A-Z][- ]?\d[A-Z]\d\b/i'`](http://ideone.com/JMyiny)

Comment: @Maria: Could you show an example that doesn't match?