# QRegExp compile time warnings

Tags: c++, qt, qregexp

I am working on some `Qt` app, whose **main window** consists of `QPlainTextEdit` subclassed **log window** for outputting events. I have three types of messages:

1. Information message, which represents a `QString` that begins with `[INFO]` substring
2. Warning message, which represents a `QString` that begins with `[WARNING]` substring
3. Error message, which represents a `QString` that begins with `[ERROR]` substring

Now, what I want to achieve with `QSyntaxHighlighter` class is to change color of these messages according to their type (**INFO** type - `Qt::DarkBlue` color, **WARNING** type - `Qt::DarkYellow` color, **ERROR** type - `Qt::DarkRed` color) and here is code chunk, which should have done the task:

```
void UeLogWindowTextHighlighter::ueSetupRules()
{
    UeHighlightRule* ueRuleInfo=new UeHighlightRule(this);
    UeHighlightRule* ueRuleWarning=new UeHighlightRule(this);
    UeHighlightRule* ueRuleError=new UeHighlightRule(this);

    this->ueInfoStartExpression()->setPattern("^[INFO].\*");        // FIRST WARNING
    this->ueWarningStartExpression()->setPattern("^[WARNING].\*");  // SECOND WARNING
    this->ueErrorStartExpression()->setPattern("^[ERROR].\*");      // THIRD WARNING

    this->ueInfoExpressionCharFormat()->setForeground(Qt::darkGray);
    this->ueWarningExpressionCharFormat()->setForeground(Qt::darkYellow);
    this->ueErrorExpressionCharFormat()->setForeground(Qt::darkRed);

    ueRuleInfo->ueSetPattern(this->ueInfoStartExpression());
    ueRuleInfo->ueSetTextCharFormat(this->ueInfoExpressionCharFormat());

    this->ueHighlightRules()->append(ueRuleInfo);

    ueRuleWarning->ueSetPattern(this->ueWarningStartExpression());
    ueRuleWarning->ueSetTextCharFormat(this->ueWarningExpressionCharFormat());

    this->ueHighlightRules()->append(ueRuleWarning);

    ueRuleError->ueSetPattern(this->ueErrorStartExpression());
    ueRuleError->ueSetTextCharFormat(this->ueErrorExpressionCharFormat());

    this->ueHighlightRules()->append(ueRuleError);
}   // ueSetupRules
```

However, when I compile the project, I get following **warnings**:

```
../../../gui/uelogwindowtexthighlighter.cpp: In member function 'void UeLogWindowTextHighlighter::ueSetupRules()': ../../../gui/uelogwindowtexthighlighter.cpp:58:47: warning: unknown escape sequence: '\*' [enabled by default]
     this->ueInfoStartExpression()->setPattern("^[INFO].\*");
                                               ^ ../../../gui/uelogwindowtexthighlighter.cpp:59:50: warning: unknown escape sequence: '\*' [enabled by default]
     this->ueWarningStartExpression()->setPattern("^[WARNING].\*");
                                                  ^ ../../../gui/uelogwindowtexthighlighter.cpp:60:48: warning: unknown escape sequence: '\*' [enabled by default]
     this->ueErrorStartExpression()->setPattern("^[ERROR].\*");
                                                ^
```

and consequently the messages are not colored (that is my suspicion). **What is wrong with my regular expressions?** I was following [this question and answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5516119/regular-expression-to-match-characters-at-beginning-of-line-only/5516148#5516148).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Star (`*`) didn't have to be escaped.  Remove the `\` or if you need the `\` it should be escaped and **write double** `\` (`\\`).