# Display all the lines where the first word is "The" or "the" using the grep command

Tags: unix

hi I know I can use `egrep -w 'The|the' f3.txt` to display all the lines with the word the but I want to display the lines where only the first word is "The" or "the"

Comment: Look at "anchoring" a regex.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular expression to match characters at beginning of line only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5516119/regular-expression-to-match-characters-at-beginning-of-line-only)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following regular expression:

```
grep -E '^(The|the)\s' texto.txt
```

For lines that end with dot:

```
grep -E '^(The|the)\s.+\.$' texto.txt
```

Add the **^** to inform you that the word should be at the beginning.

Comment: `grep -P` is extremely nonportable (a GNU-only option that's only available if linked with libpcre, and so isn't always available even when guaranteed to be using modern GNU grep). No reason to provide an answer that's restricted to it when one compatible with POSIX grep is possible.

Comment: Also, this will match `Theo` -- it isn't performing a word-level match.

Comment: Better, as amended, but `\s` isn't available in standard ERE either. Some libc implementations may provide it as an extension, but the safe option is to use `[[:space:]]` -- or, more appropriately, `([[:space:]]|$)` (since `The` is still a word even if it's the *only* word on a line).

Comment: (Also, right now, the `\s` is only on the `the` branch, not on the `The` branch).

Comment: And what if I wanted to display all the lines that contain a "." at the end?

Comment: Btw I also didn't understand what the -E does in the first command

Comment: @BetaCrasher, the `-E` specifies ERE syntax ("extended regular expressions"), not default BRE syntax. ERE is generally the right thing -- it's (unlike PCRE) guaranteed to be available everywhere, and (unlike BRE) it's not awful.

Comment: That said, this is likely not to work on several platforms account of the use of (PCRE-only) `\s`, which *really* should be `[[:space:]]`.

Comment: @BetaCrasher, ...as for searching for a `.` at the end, that would be something like `grep -E '[.]$'`

Comment: Why have square brackets when you had round in the first one does it not make a diference

Comment: BTW, `egrep` is exactly the same thing as `grep -E`.

Comment: @BetaCrasher, the square brackets set up a character class -- that is to say, an expression with square brackets will match exactly one character unless modified by something that changes the number of times it's matched. A character class containing only `.` is a way to match a period that is less sensitive to escaping issues than backslash-escaping `'\.'`. (Backslashes can get messy, especially when nesting different kinds of quoting contexts; avoiding them is cleaner).

Comment: Thank u this helped very much

Comment: @BetaCrasher, ...so, to be clear, the bracket type *absolutely* makes a difference. In `(.)`, it's matching any character (`.` is a wildcard in regex). In `[.]`, it's matching only one character, the period. Similarly, `[ao]` matches one character, either an `a` or an `o`, whereas `(ao)` only matches the string `ao` in that exact order.