# Removing first alphabetic character from string

Tags: r, regex, excel

I have a column that contains alphanumeric data. I would like to remove the alphabetic character only if it's in the beginning of the string.

Example of what the data looks like:
**Z**999999999
12**ABC**
123456**AB**7

What I would like the data to look like:
999999999
12**ABC**
123456**AB**7

Comment: What have you tried and where have you run into problems?  Do the bolded letters need to be retained as bold?  Where do you expect the output to be?

Comment: What if there are two alphabetic characters at the start of the string? Do you remove both or only the first one?

Comment: Also dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/a/22670370/3832970

Answer (score 3):

You need to use **regular expression**:

```
sub(pattern = "^[a-zA-Z]",replacement = "",x = "Z999999999 12ABC 123456AB7")
```

Read:

https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/RegExCheatsheet.pdf

Answer (score 2):

```
library(stringr)
x <- 'Z999999999 12ABC 123456AB7'
str_replace(x, '^[a-zA-Z]','') # find a leading letter and replace it with nothing
```